# Apps on ubuntu 20.04 not opening after upgrade

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, 20.04

[image]

After running `sudo apt upgrade` in my Ubuntu 20.04, most of my apps are not opening, not even the terminal. I don't know how google chrome is opening though. I tried running `sudo apt autoremove`, `sudo apt-get install -f`, `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` on the virtual terminal and also tried changing the python version in /usr/bin/gnome-terminal but nothing works. Please help me out!

Also, this error message (see the link) is showing in the activity bar. I tried googling the error but got nothing. Please help me out!

Comment: I'd switch to a text terminal, and enter `python -V; python3 -V` as have you tried changing the default version of `python`?   Ubuntu relies on `python` quite extensively, and those features will stop working if default versions are changed incorrectly.

Comment: Also add the output of "sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade" to your question: the error messages may give a hint. Add the output of `apt policy | grep http` to show all PPA's you have enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo dpkg --configure -a` or `sudo apt install -f`

The first one will check to see if there are any packages that weren't fully installed and the second one will attempt to install any missing dependencies.

Comment: This saved me from reinstalling the OS from scratch. I mistakenly restarted the system when updates were happening in the background. After that I could not do regular login. Thanks to this answer, I loggedin to a terminal session and fix the broken updates. After that I could reboot normally.